# Argument is a union, return type is constrained to a subset of that union

Tags: typescript

I want a function that takes one of a finite set of constructors (unrelated by superclass), and returns object of the given type:

```
class Foo { name: string }
class Bar { age: number }

type AllowedTypes =
    typeof Foo
  | typeof Bar;

function buildAThing(constructor: AllowedTypes) {
    return new constructor();
}
```

This function takes a Foo *or* a Bar, and I want the return type to match what's actually passed.

I know I can describe this with overloads:

```
function buildAThing(constructor: typeof Foo): Foo;
function buildAThing(constructor: typeof Bar): Bar;
function buildAThing(constructor: AllowedTypes) {
    return new constructor();
}
```

However, I'd like to be able to have other functions that call this function without having to redeclare every overload in this other function as well.

Writing it like this produces an error:

```
function usesBuildAThing(constructor: AllowedTypes) {
    return buildAThing(constructor);
}
```

> "Argument of type 'AllowedTypes' is not assignable to parameter of type 'typeof Bar'.
>     Type 'typeof Foo' is not assignable to type 'typeof Bar'.
>       Property 'age' is missing in type 'Foo' but required in type 'Bar'"

Is there some other way I can achieve what I'm after here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use generics to explicitly specify the return type:

```
function buildAThing<T extends AllowedTypes>(ctor: T): InstanceType<T> {
    return new ctor() as InstanceType<T>;
}
```

[Demo](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Foo%20%7B%20name%3A%20string%20%7D%0D%0Aclass%20Bar%20%7B%20age%3A%20number%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20AllowedTypes%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20typeof%20Foo%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7C%20typeof%20Bar%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20buildAThing%3CT%20extends%20AllowedTypes%3E(ctor%3A%20T)%3A%20InstanceType%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20ctor()%20as%20InstanceType%3CT%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20x%3A%20Foo%20%3D%20buildAThing(Foo)%3B)

Comment: You're a hero. Thanks!